# Exporting Matlab figure to .dxf using file exchange´s DXFLib

Tags: matlab, export

**Problem**

I am trying to export my matlab plot to a .dxf format. I am using this library [DXFlib](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33884-dxflib)

I am using the following function of the library:

```
FID = dxf_polymesh(FID, VERTICES, FACES, varargin)
```

My plot is created of an alphashape:

```
h=plot(shp1,'FaceColor','red');
```

So I try to use the function by:

```
dxf_polymesh('test.dxf',h.Vertices,h.Faces)
```

> Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.
>
> Error in dxf_polymesh (line 75)   fclose(FID.fid);

In the test file of the library FID is described as follows:

> FID is a structure containing handle to DXF file and parameters that
>   are used by remaining routines. DXFLib is a 'state' library.

**Questions**

This is probably a quite simple/stupid question:

1. What does FID in a content like this mean ( I know it stands for file identifier) but is this in this case the file I want to create, an existing file or something completly else ?
2. I guess I have some kind of wrong FID input from this error, what would be the right thing to enter in that function ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's exactly what the file is telling you: it's a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) containing the handle to the DXF file (an actual `fID` returned by `fopen`) along with the parameters used by the remaining functions. While it's a very poorly named variable in my opinion, its contents are clearly stated.

Comment: I suggest you follow the instructions provided by the author and go through [`dxf_test`](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33884-dxflib/content/dxf_test.m) and the supporting functions to see how to use the toolbox.